# In powerpoint VBA, how to change the spacing of a font in a textbox?

Tags: vba, powerpoint, spacing

Do you know what the command in VBA is in order to space out some text? 
I looked on the internet and didn't find anything that would work.

this "SOMMAIRE" textbox has no spacing

[image: not spaced out]

and this, is what I want that textbox to look like :
[image]

there is more space in between the letters

more exactly, I am looking for the VBA code for this exact button :
[image]

Comment: Can you be more descriptive for "Space out some Text"?  Do you mean Text Alignment or are you looking to add several textboxes and how would you space them out evenly across a page?

Comment: Like [this](http://memecrunch.com/meme/2DLYB/spaced-out-face/image.jpg)?  No, but seriously, what do you mean by "space out" -- do you mean paragraph alignment Justified?

Comment: You can probably find the answer via the [Documentation for PowerPoint Object Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff743835(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: I added pictures, but yes, it is space between the letters of "SOMMAIRE" @davidZemmens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the shape's `.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Spacing` property. By default it is probably `0`. You can change it to other values to increase the font spacing.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. paragraphformat is not what I am looking for. Im looking for something that has more to do with the font style itself

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add that auto-kerning is also a factor so you'll want to remove that too:

```
'Set character point spacing to zero
.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Spacing = 0

'Remove automatic kerning
.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Kerning = False
```

The kerning property can be viewed manually if you select the shape and in the Font group on the HOME ribbon, click the notch in the bottom right and then go to the Character Spacing tab - you will see a checkbox there where this property is set.