# How to change characters spacing in Powerpoint with C#

Tags: c#, powerpoint, office-interop, kerning

I just want to update the characters spacing in Powerpoint with C#, but I don't know how to do it.  I iterate `Slides` and `Shapes`, but I cannot find a `Spacing` property in `Font` like Word.

```
int slideCount = pprst.Slides.Count;
for (int s = 1; s <= slideCount; ++s )
{
    MSPPT.Slide slide = pprst.Slides[s];
    int shapeCount = slide.Shapes.Count;
    for (int h = 1; h <= shapeCount; ++h)
    {
        MSPPT.Shape shape = slide.Shapes[h];
        MSPPT.TextRange textRange = shape.TextFrame.TextRange;
    }

}
```

Comment: By "characters spacing" do you mean the spacing between characters?  That's otherwise known as "[kerning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning)".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In powerpoint VBA, how to change the spacing of a font in a textbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32846510/in-powerpoint-vba-how-to-change-the-spacing-of-a-font-in-a-textbox).  The key is getting an instance of the [`Font2` interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.core.font2?view=office-pia), which has the `Kerning` and `Spacing` properties you need.

Comment: Thanks so much! That is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Just paste the code here if someone need it.

```
                            MSPPT.Slide slide = pprst.Slides[s];
                            int shapeCount = slide.Shapes.Count;
                            for (int h = 1; h <= shapeCount; ++h)
                            {
                                MSPPT.Shape shape = slide.Shapes[h];
                                if (shape.HasTextFrame == MsoTriState.msoTrue)
                                {
                                    if (shape.TextFrame2.HasText == MsoTriState.msoTrue)
                                    {
                                        shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Spacing = 0;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        continue;
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    continue;
                                }
                            }
```